# How to use nested if

Tags: prolog

for example:

```
testif(X,Y) :-
    X >= 6 ->
        writeln('X> 6'),
        Y>= 3 ->
            writeln('X >6 and Y> 3');
        writeln('X >6 and Y<3'),        

    writeln('X<6');
    writeln('Test over').

test(X,Y):-
    testif(X,Y).


?- test(7, 3).
Yes (0.00s cpu)
X> 6
X >6 and Y> 3
```

why don't output 'Test over' ?

```
?- test(4, 3).
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
X >6 and Y<3    % why output this line?
X<6
```

why don't output 'Test over' too?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want to write:

```
testif(X,Y) :-
    X >= 6 ->
        (writeln('X>= 6'), Y>=3 -> writeln('X >=6 and Y>=3'); writeln('X >=6 and Y<=3')) ; 
        writeln('X<6'),
    writeln('Test over').

test(X,Y):-
    testif(X,Y).
```

`;` means `or` and `,` means `and` in Prolog, I think you should you parentheses to separate them and make sure meanings of clauses are what you expect.

Comment: Thanks very much, You describe very clearly,This is my first time to see how to use parentheses :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the idiomatic way of writing a (nested) if-then-else in Prolog:

```
testif(X,Y) :-
    (X >= 6 ->
        writeln('X> 6'),
        (Y>= 3 ->
            writeln('X >6 and Y> 3')
        ;
            writeln('X >6 and Y<3'),
        )
    ;
        writeln('X<6');
    ),
    writeln('Test over').
```

As in any other language, indentation counts in Prolog. See [Covington *et al.*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899) for a styleguide.

Comment: Thanks firstly, your site doesn't work: http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899,  Access Denied
Sadly, your client "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; QQDownload 665; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; Tablet PC 2.0)

Comment: @funlive: try another browser or change your proxy/firewall settings.

Comment: +1 for this nicer style; I write Prolog this way too. I'll add that indentation certainly counts for _readability_ in Prolog (as in most other languages), but doesn't typically matter as far as most Prolog interpreters go (as opposed to say, Python, where sometimes indentation can be crucial and has meaning).